# weblogic ssl handshake failure trust store issue

Tags: ssl, weblogic, handshake, truststore

I am getting ssl handshake failure when i try to invoke https service call within weblogic. 
I have added the server certificate into weblogic trust store -"cacerts".

Command used to add the trust store in weblogic startup script :

```
     JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore="/weblogic92/server/lib/cacerts" ${JAVA_OPTIONS}"
```

export JAVA_OPTIONS

Am i missing anything else - Any pointers to fix this issue ?

Tested the ssl connection within app server box using SSLPoke.java and it was successful.

```
   java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/weblogic92/server/lib/cacerts 
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit SSLPoke 192.16.2.6 8443
```

Weblogic server log trace:

```
       javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1628)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:230)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:224)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1027)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:120)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:574)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:510)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:888)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1117)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:629)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
```

Comment: Could it be a quotes problem? try JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore=/weblogic92/server/lib/cacerts" ${JAVA_OPTIONS}

Comment: @Xargos - No its not a quote problem , i even tried using a variable. Although SSL option is displayed in the startup logs, when i do ssl invocation - i get errors in the application level.

Comment: So when you do a `keytool -v -list -keystore /weblogic92/server/lib/cacerts` you can see your server? Also you can try: `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/weblogic92/server/lib/cacerts`

Comment: Which is the solution answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are several other things you could try:

1. Have you also tried JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore=/weblogic92/server/lib/cacerts"
2. Try adding the certificates using the console (servers->server_name->keystores)
3. You might also have to add following java options:

   1. -Dweblogic.security.SSL.verbose=true
   2. -Dweblogic.security.SSL.enable.renegotiation=true
   3. -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true
4. In servers->server_name->SSL (advanced) check Use JSSE SSL.
5. Check Use server certs.
6. Change Hostname Verification to None

Comment: i dont see any option "In servers->server_name->SSL (advanced) check Use JSSE SSL." in the weblogic admin console. I use 9.2.2 weblogic server. Tried options 1 and 3.

Comment: Currently in the logs , i could see this setting  "java.protocol.handler.pkgs = weblogic.utils|weblogic.utils|weblogic.utils|weblogic.net" , do i need to make any change handler.pkgs ?

Comment: I have a admin and 2 managed instances - above settings 1 and 3 are applied to startup scripts in the managed instance level. Do i need to applied it to the admin instance ??

Comment: hm... didn't realize the it was weblogic 9.2.2 (weblogic92 could have been a pointer). In such case this might not work, since I was writing this having WebLogic 11g in mind. As to the last comment I usually add it in setDomainEnv.sh (not sure if this file exists in your version), but you shouldn't need to add it to admin instance. Btw, did doing 1 and 3 cause a different error, or is it still the same?

Comment: At last, I could resolve this issue thanks to your "Change hostname verification" pointer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that this is very old thread, but since I faced the same challenge when getting my web application that is deployed on Weblogic (12.1) to communicate to an external webservice over HTTPS and worked through various solution to finally get it to work, few pointers from my work is provided in hope that it will be helpful to someone in future.

Oracle's official document on this topic is available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24422/identity_trust.htm#SECMG382)

```
How WebLogic Server Locates Trust
---------------------------------

WebLogic Server uses the following algorithm when it loads its trusted CA certificates:

1. If the keystore is specified by the -Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAkeystore 
   command-line argument, load the trusted CA certificates from that keystore.
2. Else if the keystore is specified in the configuration file (config.xml), load 
   trusted CA certificates from the specified keystore. If the server is configured 
   with DemoTrust, trusted CA certificates will be loaded from the 
   WL_HOME\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks and the JDK cacerts keystores.
3. Else if the trusted CA file is specified in the configuration file (config.xml), 
   load trusted CA certificates from that file (this is only for compatibility 
   with 6.x SSL configurations).
4. Else load trusted CA certificates from WL_HOME\server\lib\cacerts keystore.
```

I tried option number 1, i.e. provided path to cacert **-Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAkeystore** having imported the certificate at recommended truststore inside the running JDK but it did not work. Although I know that the import was successful as it works with a Java class that I wrote to access same HTTPS location by running it on same JDK but from outside of Weblogic.

Subsequently, I tried option number 2, i.e. I imported the certificate in DemoTrust.jks located at WL_HOME\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks. This **SUCCESSFULLY** allowed my deployed web application to communicate with external webservice over HTTPS

Comment: Simpe way to do option 2 is : http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com/2016/07/wls-how-to-import-ssl-cert-into-wls.html

Answer (score 0):

It is a quotes problem. Remove the pointless inner quotation marks:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore=/weblogic92/server/lib/c‌​acerts ${JAVA_OPTIONS}"
```